# how to redirect to login page of another project in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two project in solution at visual studio 2010.after sign up completion in one project i want to redirect it to login page of  another project.i don't know how to do it.help .thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the page response and redirect the page like this

Response.Redirect("http:://YOUR page path");